# Integrating Hibernate to Spring running on embedded jetty

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, configuration

I have just returned to Spring after 5 years of gap and it seems lot is changed. I have a task to create a REST Service using Spring with hibernate as an ORM, So far I am able to run a basic Rest Service using embedded jetty and able to make GET/POST calls, the next is to integrate hibernate into it so that the data fetch/Sent operation actually use MySQL instead of sending hard-coded response(which I have done currently).

The issue is earlier I used to work on Spring MVC using Tomcat where we had web.xml to define the dispatcher servlet and application-context which in turn were used to define hibernate config and other beans declaration, but now having embedded jetty I am not finding a way to integrate hibernate to my REST app, Is the way to add configuration is changed from XML to class based config. I searched over internet but maybe I am out of words or not using correct keywords, in short, Have no luck finding some solution to integrate hibernate to my Spring app which is using embedded jetty.

Could some please breif me about the recent changes or point me to the right tutorial ?

*Any help appreciated, thanks in advance !*

***ps - I have used this example to progress so far https://github.com/pethoalpar/SpringMvcJettyExample***

Comment: embedded jetty ? Are you using spring-boot ?

Comment: Nopes, is it something like I have to use spring-boot for embedded jetty ? I simply followed this link https://github.com/pethoalpar/SpringMvcJettyExample

Comment: not necessary but spring-boot is one of the options , please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , lot of changes in these 5 years and one of the game-changer is spring-boot

If you want to build a brand new project especially if you want to run the web application on the embedded container such as Jetty , you can check out spring-boot.It already provides integration with Jetty , hibernate and Spring MVC REST service.

The end result is that you  just need to change a little bit configuration (most probably the DB connection info) and you can quickly get a production-ready REST service backed by JPA/Hibernate which can just run without any XML configuration anymore.

There are tons of tutorials in Internet talking about how to do it . You should easily find them out such as [this](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-2-hibernate-5-jpa-mysql-crud-rest-api) using the keywords something likes "springboot webservice hibernate jetty" etc.

Comment: if the naming notion is changed with spring, by Spring MVC I always considered the web application only which has some frontend also. Does Spring MVC REST means the same as core backend with REST APIs and no frontend ? I need only the backend rest services I don't have to build any frontend. And also thanks for the response I will check spring boot now.

Comment: Yes . They enhance Spring MVC some years ago such that it can implement REST web service too. So when people talk about Spring MVC , basically it can mean a pure backend REST API or a controller that process the request from  a view (e.g. JSP) / generate response to view depending on the context.

Comment: thanks for your responses ! they proved really helpful.

Comment: Ken Chan : would you like to pitch in here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54304646/is-handling-very-large-concurrency-is-not-possible/ ?

Comment: @Bruce_Wayne ,well ,  I am not the expert of very high scalable architecture , but someone mentions LMAX architecture  , which is interesting and worthy to look at it. And it seems that your bottleneck is in the database , if requirements are allowed ,  using BASE consistency model normally provided by NoSQL should be more easier to scale than the relational DB 's ACID  consistency model... Of course theoretically , , you can increase the relational database scaleability by configuring a DB cluster with many nodes.....